# Refresh the data in controller when scope gets changed in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm pretty new with angular and I've read a lot of threads here and googled this topic but I cannot get a clear answer. what i am really trying to achieve is. lets suppose I have a controller A, this is a actual source for data. I passed it to one directive through binding it to a HTML. From this directive I am acually getting the source at another controller.
So I need to find out the way where I can change the data of controller when the data of controller A gets changed.

**Controller A**

```
angular.module('page.leadAndOpportunity.ctrl', []).controller('LeadAndOpportunityController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, leadAndOpportunityService) {

    $scope.selectDataSource = function (condition) {
        var dataSource = [];
        var dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.filter(function (item) {
            return item.typeName === condition;
        });
        $scope.leadsDataSource = [];
        $scope.leadsDataSource = dataSource;
        console.log($scope.leadsDataSource);
    }

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-senab-grid datasource="{{ leadsDataSource }}" defaultdata="{{defaultColumns}}" skipdata="{{ skipColumns }}" enablepersonalisation="true"></ng-senab-grid>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('page.gridView.drct', []).directive("ngSenabGrid", ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "pages/gridView/page.gridView.tpl.html",
            scope: {
                enablePersonalisation: "@enablepersonalisation",
                datasource: "@datasource",
                defaultdata: "@defaultdata",
                skipdata: "@skipdata"
            },
        }
    }]
);
```

**Controller B**

```
 var _datasource = JSON.parse($scope.datasource);
//rest the data follows
```

So when `$scope.leadsDataSource` gets changes on **Controller A**, then the

```
var _datasource = JSON.parse($scope.datasource);
```

also should get changed

I dont know if it is possible or not. But I need to change the data
Thanks in advance

Comment: have isolated scope variable as either `<` or `=` to preserve the type of object, if you use `@` then all data will get stringified.

Comment: like? if you can explain me ...I have already said, I am new to Angular stuff

Comment: how do you pass datasource from directive to controller B?

Comment: when we bind something to html by controller, it is available in directive, and its vice versa is also possible.@gaurav5430

Answer (score 2):

remove the curly brackets of the variable.since this is a directive no need to add curly brackets

```
<ng-senab-grid datasource="leadsDataSource" defaultdata="defaultColumns" skipdata="skipColumns" enablepersonalisation="true"></ng-senab-grid>
```

if u want to get the value of the variable then use "=" if u use "&" it will only get the string

```
 scope: {
            enablePersonalisation: "=enablepersonalisation",
            datasource: "=datasource",
            defaultdata: "=defaultdata",
            skipdata: "=skipdata"
           },
```

also inject the directive module to ur angular module

```
angular.module('page.leadAndOpportunity.ctrl', ['page.gridView.drct'])
```

Comment: are you sure this will work, I dont think so. This will update the directive, but data will not get refreshed, as new data is not available to the controller @IT13122256 Ranawaka R.A.S.M

Comment: can u provide a plnkr or something

Answer (score 2):

A simple explanation to keep in mind about different types of scopes would be below.

`@` Attribute string binding (String)

`=` Two-way model binding (model)

`&` Callback method binding (method)

According this you should be using Two-way binding instead of Attribute string binding because The model in parent scope is linked to the model in the directive's isolated scope. Changes to one model affects the other, and vice versa.

I would prefer using **bindToController** property definition in the directive.  When set to true in a directive with isolated scope that uses controllerAs, the component’s properties are bound to the controller rather than to the scope.
That means, Angular makes sure that, when the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolated scope bindings are available on this, and future changes are also automatically available.

Check the Below sample fiddle example for more understanding

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.fullname = 'Keshan';
  }
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.fullname = 'Fill Your Name';
  }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },

    controller: function($scope) {
      this.name = 'Fill Your Name';
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '{{ctrl.name}}',
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
  <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  <my-directive name="fullname"></my-directive>
</div>
```

[Further Reading](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)